# NodeJS express get request is not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am developing a web app. I developed everything on local and all the systems is fine. I published the app on digitalocean. When I enter the site from desktop everything is fine but on mobile, express get requests are not working.

this is the code on app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Listening at 3000"));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json({limit: '1mb'}));
const hogan = require('hogan.js');
const fs = require('fs');

//GOOGLE PLACES AUTO COMPLETE
app.get('/placesAC/:input', async (request, response) => {
    const userInput = request.params['input'];    
    const placesAPI = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?';
    const placeConditions = '&region=tr';
    const APIKey = '&key=MY_API_KEY';
    const input = 'input=' + userInput;

    const finalURL = placesAPI + input + placeConditions + APIKey;

    const fetch_response = await fetch(finalURL);
    const json = await fetch_response.json();

    response.json(json);

    console.log(userInput);
});
```

and this is how I am fetching it from the client.

```
    const inputVal = fromText.value;
    const apiURL = '/placesAC/' + inputVal;
    const response = await fetch(apiURL);
    const json = await response.json();
```

Comment: Are you sure the express server is exposed to the internet (or a network the mobile device can access)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was from event listener. When you use `addEventListener("keypress")` it works on desktop but mobile. So I added OnKeyPress from html inside  tag and problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

For your API call, try to add try-catch to handle the errors,maybe it helps you to debug what's wrong with your code

```
try {
      const apiURL = '/placesAC/'+ inputVal;
      const response = await fetch(apiURL);
    if (!response.ok) // or check for response.status
        throw new Error(response.statusText);

        const json = await response.json();
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but how I am supposed to be see console log on mobile? I have nothing wrong on desktop but on mobile.